# Android : Checking if same R.drawable.image is used

Tags: android, compare, bitmapfactory

I'm working on a canvas in which I've created several bitmaps.

```
b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image)
```

When the user taps the bitmap on the canvas, I want to check which image it is using to determine if it should be changed.

In my `onTouchEvent` I have, bmps is an array of these Bitmaps:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  bmps.size()-1; i++) {
        Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
        if (bmp.didGetTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            // code here
        }
```

I want to be able to check if this property is set to `R.drawable.image` or set to something else.

Images are all the same width and height so I can't compare them that way.

Comment: Just store a reference to last displayed bmp?

Comment: yeah, keep them stored... they are integers, don't take much memory... I wish I could say the same for the bitmaps

Comment: when perform any of action to `Bitmap` may `setTag()` and when action in `onTouch()` `if(getTag != null)` ?

Comment: I was thinking that, but was hoping for something else.  Thanks guys